# @@identity immediate use

Tags: mybatis, identity-column

Say I have this MYBATIS statement:

```
<insert id="insertValue" resultType="car" > 
   BEGIN TRANSACTION
      INSERT INTO table1 ( somefield,... ) VALUES ( #{value},... ); 

      <selectKey keyProperty="carId" resultClass="int"> 
         SELECT @@IDENTITY as carId 
      </selectKey>

      UPDATE table2
      set fieldx = #{carId}
      where table2Id = 500;
   COMMIT
</insert>
```

I am getting value 0 for carId, should be the key to the just added record into table1

How do I grab the recently generated keyValue for immediate use?

Comment: Your post is very difficult to read, consider cleaning it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is :

```
insert table1 ......
declare @var int
set @var= scope_identity()
update table2 set ... where id = @var
```

Comment: Thank You for your quick reply;  Got it working;  Did not need the @@Identity at all;  processed the insert statement, then update table2 set fieldx = (select max(id) from table1) where ...

Comment: If two people call the stored procedure / SQL / function at the same time, your select max(id) could get the wrong id.  With scope_identity() it won't happen.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to "set fieldx = scope_identity()" - works!!